# Drawing HTML table with dynamic columns/rows

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const reports = [
      {
        user: "John",
        document: [
          {            
            document_name: "word",
            document_type: 1,
            cid: 2,
          },
          {           
            document_name: "excel",
            document_type: 1,
            cid: 2,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        user: "Matt",
        document: [
          {            
            document_name: "access",
            document_type: 1,
            cid: 1,
          },
          {            
            document_name: "word",
            document_type: 1,
            cid: 3,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

Is there a way to draw a HTML table where columns would be the users, and rows would be document_names (in both cases without duplicates). So, someting like this.

|  | John | Matt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| word | 2 | 1 |
| excel | 2 |  |
| access |  | 1 |

Cells with numeric values are populated with corresponding `cid` values.

Any help, even regarding `const reports` refactor, is appreciated.

Comment: Can you actually refactor the structure, or are you looking for a JavaScript function to translate it into a table?

Comment: I'm looking for a JavaScript logic for populating table in a desired way, but if that's impossible or hard to accomplish, I'm more than open to advice on how to refactor `reports` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are created row-wise, not column wise. That is to say in HTML the row `tr` is the wrapper for several columns. This is important for your problem, since your structure is organised column-wise (user first, not document first).

At the same time, the number of columns is dynamic (determined by your data), and needs to be the same in all rows, even if a user is missing. The same counts for the rows. While the data can have gaps, the table cannot.

So by creating separate lists first, you can iterate easier on the two dimensions. [In Database Theory this is called Normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Part of normalization is to only store unique items, so you can use [JavaScript Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). When you `add()` an item, it’s only added once, avoiding duplicates.

```js
// this is pseudo-code to demonstrate the target structures
const users = Set(2) [ "John", "Matt" ];
const docs = Set(3) [ "word", "excel", … ]
const usages = [{user: "John", doc: "word", cid: 2}, …]
```

Then you can use [`for … in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over your sets and create the columns and rows.

To make things easier, you can prepare the static structure of the table, and then use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add the dynamic elements to the table.

You should create a table using [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) and [`<th>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) to semantically associate the data. This will not only help users with disabilities navigate the table through assistive technology, it will also repeat the table head in printout.

```js
const reports = [{
    user: "John",
    document: [{
        document_name: "word",
        document_type: 1,
        cid: 2,
      },
      {
        document_name: "excel",
        document_type: 1,
        cid: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    user: "Matt",
    document: [{
        document_name: "access",
        document_type: 1,
        cid: 1,
      },
      {
        document_name: "word",
        document_type: 1,
        cid: 3,
      },
    ],
  },
];

// Normalise data

const users = new Set(reports.map(r => r.user));
const docs = new Set();
const usages = [];

reports.forEach(r => r.document.forEach(d => {
  docs.add(d.document_name);
  usages.push({
    user: r.user,
    doc: d.document_name,
    cid: d.cid
  });
}));

// Add to the table

// Create headers
const theadTr = document.querySelector('thead tr');
for (const u of users) {
  const th = document.createElement('th');
  th.innerHTML = u;
  theadTr.appendChild(th);
}

// Create data rows
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
for (const d of docs) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  const th = document.createElement('th');
  th.innerHTML = d;
  tr.appendChild(th);
  
  for (const u of users) {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      const ud = usages.find(ud => ud.user === u && ud.doc === d);
      
      if (ud) td.innerHTML = ud.cid;
      tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
th, td {
  padding: .2em .5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

thead tr {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Document usage per user and document type</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```